# Is there some kind of concordance of real-world references for Saberhagen's Berserker stories?

Tags: berserker

Having been a fan of Fred Saberhagen's *Berserker* stories and novels since I was a child, I have often wondered whether I was getting all the real-world references.  Is there some kind of (probably fan-created) document explaining most or all of the real-world events and people that the stories allude to?

The references begin in earnest with "Stone Place," which retells the story of the Battle of Lepanto in outer space.  The Turks become berserkers, Castile becomes Esteel, and (as I realized only years later) the Venetians become Venusians.  The real-world ramming tactics of galley warfare are transferred to ramming and boarding the original city-sized berserkers.

As I just noted, I missed the Venetian/Venusian connection for decades.  There are probably more historical allusions that I missed.  In *Berserker Fury*, the whole order of battle is based on the 1942 Battle of Midway; but I only learned that when I went looking for more information about the book online, since the whole setup seemed wrong to me.  (I noticed that it felt more like a aircraft carrier naval battle than was usual in berserker stories, but until I saw it pointed out in a review, I didn't make the connection to Midway.)

Figuring out these references is complicated by the fact that Saberhagen uses a variety of names from all sorts of Earth cultures.  It's not always obvious whether they are merely for flavor, and to emphasize the inter-cultural character of Earth's future spacefaring civilization, or whether they are refer to specific historical events or personages such as the Knights Templar.

The fact that Saberhagen also included allusions to fiction only makes things trickier.  "Masque of the Red Shift" is clearly an extended allusion, but not to real-world events.  However, is the synthetic god Thodur a reference to Thor in universe or only out of universe?  There's probably no way to answer that one conclusively.

Still, I'm wondering if there exists some kind of concordance explaining Saberhagen's extensive web of historical references, as best they can be worked out.

Comment: Not ready for a full answer, but "Berserker: Blue Death" borrows **heavily** from Moby Dick...